# Compiler Error Message: CS1061 how?

Tags: asp.net

`product_aspx` does not contain a definition for `txtName_TextChanged` and no extension method `txtName_TextChanged` accepting a first argument of type `product_aspx` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 8:      </p>
Line 9:      <p>
Line 10:         <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
Line 11:         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" CssClass="valid" ErrorMessage="Required!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
Line 12:         <asp:Label ID="lblEname" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: You need to provide the specific source code that is producing this error. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you recompile after adding `txtName_TextChanged` to the code behind file?

Comment: Is the method in the code behind file private? It needs to be protected or public for the aspx page to see it.